# PHP код и Денвер

Tags: php, denwer

Я создал php документ, поместил его на локальный сервер Денвер. Код следующий:

```
<body>
<?php

$name = "Александр";
$age = 25;

echo "$name";

?>
</body>
```

но при выводе в браузере вместо слова Александр - набор символов, заголовок страницы тоже отображается криво. Если написать на английском - все ок. Кодировку менял - и utf-8, и windows-1251. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, господа, решилось само-собой. ) Спишем на мою неопытность. )

Comment: Кодировка файла?)

Comment: Честно говоря, сам толком не понял) поменял снова на windows-1251, сохранил-обновил и все стало на свои места.

Comment: Понятно) На будущее - попробуйте привыкнуть к UTF8 и проверяйте, чтобы в нем была 1) БД перед занесением данных (многие потом страдали), 2) файлы, 3) заголовки и теги <meta>. И наверно стоит закрыть вопрос)

Comment: Это само-собой - все будет. Я только начинаю. Спасибо за помощь. )